# Delete a row added with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a project when I want create a dynamic list of items before proceed to save the information, I'm using Jquery and append to create the table, I'm trying to remove the entire row from the Resumee table, I'm removing with jquery $('ID').remove but this logic doesn't work when I delete randon items from the table.

I want to know if there is a way to delete the entire rown withouth having a specific ID

My project here: jsfiddle.net/yGjFR/7/

Blue Button = ADD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function delrow(){
    $('table tr').click( function() {
    $(this).remove();
    });     
 }
```

Comment: I saw that example before but I though I should replace "table" with my table ID, working right now, thank you.